# Firewall Feedthrough 2002 Infiniti I35

Tags: infiniti, firewall

I'm in the process of installing a pair of supplementary LED lights on my 2002 Infiniti I35 to help with night visibility on the dark, windy mountain roads around here. I bought a wiring harness on Amazon that includes a switch and relay that happens to fit perfectly in an empty slot left of the steering wheel but I'm stumped finding a place to feed the wire through the firewall. Is there a relatively convenient place to pass the wire through? If not, I'll resort to [drilling my own hole](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25376/safe-way-to-drill-through-the-engine-bay-firewall) but I'd rather use an existing feedthrough if one exists. I'm pretty handy but I don't have a lift to look at the firewall properly, so I'm crawling around under the dash looking for where the wires feed through. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!